# Why does including Amazon ads prevent all the AdSense ads from showing?

Tags: google-adsense

This is really odd. I've had a 3 adsense + 2 amazon ad set up for my blog  for months. Yesterday I updated an amazon ad from black friday to cyber monday with this code

```
<iframe src="http://rcm-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=thetodlif-20&o=1&p=26&l=ur1&    
category=cyber2014&banner=1PY6R9RS79W616ZWVZ02&f=ifr&linkID=VF3A62ZEBVVFLT62" 
width="468" height="60" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" 
frameborder="0">
```

1 amazon ad and 1 adsense code are on all posts (beginning and end) then the other 2 adsense and 1 amazon are in the side bar of the main side so appear on pages and posts. Meaning at any given time there is no more than 3 adsense ads, 2 on pages, 3 on posts. Well, after I switched to the ad code above the sidebar ads vanished on posts. I eventually experimented with just removing the new amazon code from the end of posts and presto, adsense in the sidebar is back. It appears they are removing the sidebar ads because the amazon ad is being viewed as adsene and putting it over the 3 ad limit.

Why would google be seeing this amazon ad as an adsense ad?

Edit: I tried a different amazon code, and that also works fine, seems to just be that cyber monday code. So, I suppose this is a for-curiosities-sake question now lol

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is a bit slow right now because of the holiday weekend, but there are some real experts here daily. I do not know enough to answer your question. Please be patient. I expect our regular users to return soon.

Comment: You should be aware that from a SEO stand point pages that are ad-heavy regardless who serves your ads can trigger a penalty on the site or pages if the advert ratio is high compared to actual content.

Comment: Generally, I keep posts to a 400 word minimum, with 600-800 being more the norm, so I doubt that's an issue. From my net going experience, my site is actually rather ad-light compared to most blogs with 2 small, 3 on the sidebar by themselves on posts, just the side bar on pages and the main.

edit: The site: [link](lifewithgremlins.com)

Comment: Your header is appearing oddly for me. Aren't there rules about the maximum number of competitor ads on the same page?

Comment: Not that I know of. If that was the case, it wouldn't have worked with a different ad code :) 

Though, could you screenshot the header weirdness for me? It looks as it should on my end.

Comment: [Google's guide on this](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ads_on_the_same_page_or_site_as_another_publisher) is very confusing, but from my interpretation they say that other ads count towards the limit

Answer (score 1):

Google used to have a limit of 3 ad units per page regardless of if they where AdSense units or unit from another advertising network.

This has changed as of August 2016 where [AdSense lifted the ad unit limit](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ad_limit_per_page) for every site. You can now place an unlimited amount of adsense ads on a page with one caveat, advertising and other paid promotional material added to your page should not exceed your content, in other words the quality of the site needs to be maintained. This is especially useful for infinite scroll where more content is added as you scroll down the page.

Based on the date and content of the original question the original issue was the fact that the two amazon ads went over the 3 unit limit and since Google couldn't disable the amazon ads they instead disabled their own ads.